# LSTM - Prepare data for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm using a LSTM in Python. In order to train the LSTM I need to tell the LSTM what the dependet variable and what the independet variable is. My dependent variable is of the shape (4432, 1), my 3D array (lstm_ivs) of independent variables is of the shape (4432, 14, 1800).

4432 single videos, 1800 frames (timesteps) and 14 independent variables.
4432 single videos, 1 dependent variable (impressions).

How do I split the data for training? How does the LSTM understand which dependent variable belongs to the corresponding independent (not to forget about the 1800 time steps)?

That's my code so far:

```
lstm_shape = 10
main_shape = 16
drop = 0.2
learn = 0.95
rho = 0.95
epochs = 100
batch_size = 64
opt = optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=learn, rho=rho)
loss_weight = 0.8
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_main_output_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='main_output_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=4)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_ivs.shape[0], activation='relu', input_shape=(lstm_ivs.shape[1], lstm_ivs.shape[2]),return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Dropout(drop))
model.add(Dense(lstm_shape,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(drop))
model.add(Dense(lstm_shape,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss='mean_squared_error')
print(model.summary())
```

So the model is running perfectly but I don't know how to start the training.

I hope you can help me.

Best
Kai

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to start the training.

To train the model you should call the `model.fit()` method.

Then, once trained, you can predict new values with `model.predict()`.

[Here](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) are the docs where you can read about the parameters to understand exactly how data should be passed.